# Rails and Mailchimp - Welcome email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailchimp, transactional

I need to send out a welcome email whenever a user registers in our website.

I have created a campaign in mailchimp for this.

I have also hooked up the hominid gem.

So, each time, I add users to the group (welcome_email group), I want to resend the campaign for the new user. Should I recreate new trans campaigns for every email?

Can I use the same campaign and just resend to the new users ?

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

Mailchimp doesn't allow sending one campaign several times, so if you have send the campaign the only way to resend it again is to copy it. Anyway it's wrong solution for welcome emails.

Mailchimp has native support for welcome email (it is called "final welcome email") and can be customized via forms settings for your list (see http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-customize-each-part-of-the-confirmation-process).

If you subscribe users via API and don't use double opt-in (I'm pretty sure this is the case), welcome email won't be sent by default. But you can force it by setting send_welcome = true flag in subscribe method (see http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/rtfm/listsubscribe.func.php).

So, you need to configure pretty welcome email and update your code to use send_welcome flag and you are ready to go, no need for campaigns.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple to setup a welcome email for your users and send those email automatically.

1) You need to have a paid account on MailChimp

2) The Official Mail website has detailed information on how to create an auto responder for welcome emails. Check the link for 
[Automatically sending welcome email whenever a user registers on the website](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-create-an-autoresponder/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Mailchimp will send a confirmation email asking users to opt-in to the mailing. You could customize these to also act as your welcome message?